# Large vertical content iOS app

Tags: ios

How can I make an app with a large vertical content?

In Xcode storyboard is not possible to drag and drop all the content I want. For example, in the App Store app you can scroll vertically, how can I do that from Xcode?

I'm reading a lot of books but none give that information for now.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: you can add then during runtime by coding,i think..

Comment: use UITableView or UIScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can drop in the content in the storyboard. Set your controller to freeform, and set its height to whatever you want (I tested using 5000). Add a scroll view to it, and pin it to all four sides of the superview. Now, add your content. Despite the fact that you made the controller and scroll view a ridiculous size, when you run the app, and look at the frames, the controller's self.view and the scroll view are the height of whatever simulator you're running, but the contentSize.height of the scroll view will be the 5000 (well, actually 4999.5 in my test).

```
2014-11-13 20:57:14.338 TallControllerTest[2180:1092368] self.view is: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2014-11-13 20:57:14.338 TallControllerTest[2180:1092368] scrollView frame is: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2014-11-13 20:57:14.338 TallControllerTest[2180:1092368] contentSize is: {320, 4999.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1 is you can use tableview and add content within it.
  [Refer For Storyboard tableviewcell](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)
- Option 2 if you want there is option to use scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show very large content vertically scrollable then you should go for either UIScrollView OR UITableView OR combination of both like UITableView with UIScrollView as subview of UITableViewCell.

If your content is really very large then go with adding views programatically that will be more convenient for large content.

At last it depends on your content and UI of how you want to represent your content.